# for loop taking too long to run

Tags: python, pandas

i have a column named data2 in dataframe df1 that contains list of nested dictionaries in each rows. there are total 50983 rows. i used the following codes but the code is taking too much time to run. inside data2 i hv id that i need to update in all dictionaries because id is unique and after that i will have to groupby using id once it is normalised into dataframe with key value pairs . the code works fine but it is taking too long time (10 minutes) .here is the code that i used :

```py
dff = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0,len(df1.data2)):
    l=df1['data2'][i]
    id_dict = [d for d in l if 'id' in d][0]
    merge = [ {**d, **id_dict} for d in l if 'id' not in d]
    dff= dff.append(merge)
```

here is the input file: [input data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wa68n4gsqhd1TuPdFph3ST_gijQwygz1/view?usp=sharing)

and my desired output should look like this : [desired output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UZj2h5w_5V_TxVdZ4w3YthM9MzRI8RZN)

Comment: I feel that this could be replaced with an `isin` method before you merge, can you show your dummy data and intended output? if it's taking longer than a few seconds for a small dataset then you aren't using pandas correctly

Comment: ok wait i show u the dummy data set

Comment: two minor notes regarding your current code: 1) `[d for d in l if 'id' in d][0]` is more efficiently done in a `for` loop that you `break` as soon as 'id' is encountered (you also don't need `l`). 2) not 100% sure but Python `append` is likely to be faster than `df.append`. So you could `append` all `merge` to a `list`, which you add to the `df` at the end.